# catch ctrl-c in c++ cause ignore scanf

Tags: c++

I'm trying to catch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. I search on google and find this code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>
#include<cstdio> using namespace std;

BOOL WINAPI ConsoleHandler(DWORD CEvent){
    if(CEvent == CTRL_C_EVENT){
        cout<<"ctrl c pressed"<<endl;
        Sleep(100);
    }
    return TRUE; }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char a[10];

    if (SetConsoleCtrlHandler( (PHANDLER_ROUTINE)ConsoleHandler,TRUE)==FALSE){
        cout<<"Unable to install handler!";
        return -1;
    }
    while(true){
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%[^\n]s",a);
        cout<<a<<endl;
    } }
```

when run this code i input "**abcd**" then it display "**abcd**" normaly and then i press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>' it display ctrl c pressed abcd**" how can i fix this code so that it just display "**ctrl c pressed**" when i press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> ?

Comment: what do you want to happen when the user press Ctrl+C aside from displaying Ctrl+C pressed?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is outputting "abcd" again is because it is still in your `a` variable from last time. The best way to fix it is to use the return value of `scanf`.  `scanf` returns the number of items filled in, so in your case you want it to return 1.

```
if (scanf("%[^\n]s", a) == 1)
    cout<<a<<endl;
```